# Bootstrap: How to make button same width as text box in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On big screens, the button is in the same line as the text box, but when zoomed in, like in smaller screens, I want the button to go below the text box but have the same width. I can't get it to work.
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" id="target" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center text-center">
                <div class="form-group form-inline">                  
                    <input type='text' class ='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 input-group' id='keyword' maxlength='25' placeholder="Text">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 text-center rounded-0 justify-content-center" value="Text">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the button inside the `div` parent of the `input`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="GET" id="target" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">                  
         <input type='text' class ='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 input-group' id='keyword' maxlength='25' placeholder="Text">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 text-center rounded-0 justify-content-center" value="Text">
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```